# How to obtain data from a website and process it in C#

Tags: c#, web, webclient, streamreader

I would like to make a console application that can query a website for data, process it, and then display it. ie- Access http://data.mtgox.com/ and then display the rate for currency X to currency Y.

I am able to get a large string of text via WebClient and StreamReader (though I don't really understand them), and I imagine that I could trim down the string to what I want and then loop the query with a delay to enable updating of the data without running the program again. However I'm only speculating and it seems like there would be a more efficient way of accessing data than this. Am I missing something?

EDIT - The general consensus seems to be to use JSON to do this; which is exactly was I was looking for! Thanks guys!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-data-from-the-web-and-map-i

Comment: `Am I missing something?` code!!  What do you expect from us. write it for you?

Comment: You'll need to add some sort of [Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx) to your project.

Comment: what you are doing is basically correct. Though processing the data is going to be hard if you dont understand what the web server is sending back. YOu should read up on HTTP and HTML

Comment: @I4V: He is asking abstract question without engaging us at details, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that site provides an API serving up JSON data.  If you don't know what JSON is you need to look into that, but basically you could create object models representing this JSON.  If you have the latest version of VS2012 you can copy the JSON and right click, hit paste special, then paste as class.  This will automatically generate models for you.  You then contact the API, retrieve the JSON, deserialize it into your models, and do whatever you want from there.

Comment: +1 and websites usually provide sample code in popular programming languages.

Comment: Thank you! I'm referencing the link that Lasse posted for this. I'm using VS2010, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to install or utilize JSON. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @user208880 JSON isn't something you install. It's a standardized way of transferring data throughout the web.  Maybe read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp). So for example, if I have the JSON

{
   "Name":"Bob",
   "Age":21
}, then I could "serialize" this into a Person object with a name property and an age property.  Like icemanind mentioned below, check out [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for easily serializing and deserializing JSON in .NET

Comment: I'm sorry, I can be a bit dense at times. As best I can tell, this is used to take in what seem to be strings of a certain format and then putting them into objects that can be used in the conventional sense. If so, that's great! That's just what I need.

That being said, I have utterly no idea how to use it. It's downloaded and unzipped, but I don't have the faintest clue how to get this to work with VS2010; assuming you even use it with that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way:

```
string url = "http://data.mtgox.com/";
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
myWebRequest.Method = "GET"; // This can also be "POST"
HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
string myPageSource = string.Empty;
myPageSource= myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
myWebResponse.Close();

// Do something with the data in myPageSource
```

Once you have the data, look at [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse it

Comment: `I am able to get a large string of text via WebClient and StreamReader` Your only addition to this is: `use Json.Net`. So nothing more than a comment.

Comment: @I4V - using `WebClient` is a huge waste of resources just to "get data" from a site. I am showing him a better way. A lot more efficient way

Comment: `using WebClient is a huge waste of resources` Why? prove it?

Comment: @I4V - Very easy to prove. Create a program using my method and create a program using the WebClient method, then run Process Explorer and see which one is consuming more CPU and memory. In addition, its just common sense that an entire `WebClient` class, which is an entire web browser would be more of a resource hog then simply making the request

Comment: You said it is more performant. So you have to show something. Otherwise my downvote remains...

Comment: BTW: `WebClient` is nothing to do with `Webbrowser`. it is just a wrapper for `HttpWebRequest` :)